# Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: messages in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.Message

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es

I built a bot using Dialogflow and connected it to a local webhook (now accessing it through ngrok). I am able to receive the response from Dialogflow but I am unable to replay to it. I followed the JSON structure as shown here - [Test response from webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/message-objects#text_response). But I am getting the following error in Dialogflow.

> Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response:
>   Cannot find field: messages in message
>   google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.Message.

Following is the reply that I sent to Dialogflow -

```
{
   "messages":[
      {
         "speech":"Text response",
         "type":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Please tell me what should be the exact format of the reply that I should send to Dialogflow.

Answer (score 3):

From v1 to v2, the response object almost change completely. For just simple text, you can use like:

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Text response",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": ["Text response"]
      }
    }
  ],
  "source": "<Text response>"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue,resolved using below json on dialogflow :

[image]

I made a simple node program which accepts a post response and returns json of the format accepted by Dialogflow.You may send your request in any way you like. check on Fulfillment status tab :

[image]

Comment: Thanks; I'm using C# and to fix "IDE1006 Naming rule violation:" I had changed fulfillmentText to FulfillmentText. After seeing your screenshot realized what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

The field [`messages`was renamed/refactored to `fulfillmentMessages`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment#fulfillment_messages) - "can not find" means that it is not a property in the definition.
This is some comparable result accepted by v2:

```
{
   "fulfillmentText": "response text",
   "fulfillmentMessages": [{"simpleResponses": {"simpleResponses": [   {
      "textToSpeech": "response text",
      "displayText": "response text"
   }]}}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Messages alone is not sufficient. Refer to Dialogflow V2 [webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#webhook) fulfillment documentation for complete list of parameters expected and format of JSON.

Are you sure you are using V2 of the DialogFlow APIs?

Comment: Vinay P Thanks for responding. I am not using their SDK. I am receiving the POST request from Dialogflow in a flask app and parsing it. I am then sending a custom reply from flask app. I Used the link that you gave but still not working. Can you tell me how to use this - https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookResponse

Comment: This another [link](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response) says that all the values are optional.

Comment: @sunil I have done similar implementation using V1, it is not sufficient to send only the fields you have considered. And again the messages error would I guess appear only in V1, because V2 doesnt seem to have   that field(I can be wrong with V2 as I havent worked on that). And I have not migrated to V2 as it is still not production ready.

Comment: Thank you @Vinay for sticking with me. I changed the agent from V2 to V1 and I changed the reply from webhook accordingly. But the question still remains - What is the exact format of reply from webhook that V2 can understand?

Comment: I would not suggest anything in V2 as I haven't moved to that yet. In V1 _displaytext_ is one field could be needed.

Comment: Cool, I will take a look at it. But the question still remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Webhook Playground](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/conversation-api-playground) to Get the appropriate response for either the Dialogflow API or the Actions SDK which is depricated but still works. There is also the yet newer and different API for the [Google Actions Builder/SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=sdk) framework as per :

DiaglowFlow JSON Response:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Webhook worked.",
              "displayText": "Webhook worked."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actions SDK Response:

```
{
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Webhook worked.",
                "displayText": "Webhook worked."
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Action Builder/SDK. Note that the session id needs to be returned.

```
{
  "session": {
    "id": "example_session_id",
    "params": {}
  },
  "prompt": {
    "override": false,
    "firstSimple": {
      "speech": "Hello World.",
      "text": ""
    }
  },
  "scene": {
    "name": "SceneName",
    "slots": {},
    "next": {
      "name": "actions.scene.END_CONVERSATION"
    }
  }
}
```